# I can't log into my admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-panel

I installed a plugin that compresses images, then I deleted it because it didn't  work. Then, I go to log into my admin panel the next day and it says

> invalid username or password

Answer (score 0):

you can login to phpmyadmin,  search for  "admin_user" field & click on that and choose MD5 and give new password & save it.

**step 1** : Login to Phpmyadmin & select proper database

**step 2:** : search for admin_user

[image]

**step 3** : click on admin_user

[image]

**step 4** : select MD5 from dropdown and type new password

[image]

**step 5** : click on "Go" button

[image]

you can find detailed explaination [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/) .

Answer (score 0):

update the password by running the following sql command from the database

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('yournewpassword') WHERE `username` = 'adminusername';
```